# Django urls behaviour with complex path

Tags: python, django, regex, django-urls

In my django project, in urls.py file i have a link like thisone:

```
...
url(r'^poliamb/(?P<m_path>\w+)/$', pol_data),
...
```

ok all work done when i have an url like:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/poliamb/test1

but i got error when i have for example

http://127.0.0.1:8000/poliamb/test1-other

if there is the - sign in the url path django get url not defined error

Someone can hel me to manage also urls with - sign?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your url regular expression is the `\w+` which matches any number of word characters. Word characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore (`_`)

`test1` passes that test, but `test1-other` does not.

Changing your regex to `r'^poliamb\/(?P<m_path>[\w\-]+)\/$'` will match urls containing dashes (`-`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match consecutive hyphens, you could optionally repeat a non capturing group containing a hyphen and 1+ word characters `(?:-\w+)*`

In the pattern there is a `/` at the end which is not in the example data. If it is optional, you could use `/?$` at the end.

```
^poliamb/(?P<m_path>\w+(?:-\w+)*)/?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7zNnAM/1)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `path` and not `url`. `url` is deprecated and replaced by `re_path`.

`str` will take any string except the slash ("/") character.

```
path(route='poliamb/<str:m_path>/', view=pol_data, name='pol_data'),
```

You can also use `slug`:

```
path(route='poliamb/<slug:m_path>/', view=pol_data, name='pol_data'),
```

Documentation:

- [django.urls functions for use in URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/)
- [Path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)